# ppa-purge fails due to "Couldn't find any package whose name is "install", but there are 154 packages which contain "install" in their name:"

Tags: package-management, ppa

Adding and then removing `ppa:graphics-drivers/dev` fails due to

```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/dev

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/dev
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:3 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                                                              
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                            
Hit:5 http://deb.playonlinux.com cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/commendsarnex/winedri3/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                                                         
Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                    
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic InRelease [21,3 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Hit:10 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                           
Hit:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                     
Hit:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                    
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wfg/0ad.dev/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                               
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                               
Hit:16 https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-runner/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages [4.100 B]
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages [2.544 B]        
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic/main Translation-en [2.144 B]       
Fetched 30,1 kB in 4s (7.730 B/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
r> sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/dev
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: graphics-drivers dev
Package revert list generated:
 install-

Disabling graphics-drivers PPA from 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-dev-cosmic.list
Updating packages lists
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package install
Couldn't find any package whose name is "install", but there are 154 packages which contain "install" in their name:
  (too many to show, the limit is 40)
Unable to apply some actions, aborting
Warning:  Something went wrong, packages may not have been reverted
```

I'm looking for a fix so that the automated downgrade routine by `ppa-purge` completes or a contact to the PPA provider so that I can inform them about the issue.

Information requested in comments:

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-dev-cosmic.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-dev-cosmic.list.save
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/dev/ubuntu cosmic main
```

and

```
> apt-cache policy ppa-purge
ppa-purge:
  Installed: 0.2.8+bzr63
  Candidate: 0.2.8+bzr63
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.8+bzr63 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

as well as

```
> aptitude search '~O LP-PPA ?installed'
i   0ad                                                                                                         - Echtzeit-Strategiespiel für antike Kriegsführung                                                                     
i A 0ad-data                                                                                                    - Echtzeit-Strategiespiel über antike Kriegsführung (Datendateien)                                                     
i A 0ad-data-common                                                                                             - Echtzeit-Strategiespiel für antike Kriegsführung (Gemeinsame Dateien)                                                
i A libclang-common-7-dev                                                                                       - clang library - Common development package                                                                           
i A libclang1-7                                                                                                 - C interface to the clang library                                                                                     
i A libclc-amdgcn                                                                                               - OpenCL C language implementation - amdgcn support                                                                    
i A libclc-dev                                                                                                  - OpenCL C language implementation - development files                                                                 
i A libclc-r600                                                                                                 - OpenCL C language implementation - r600 support                                                                      
i A libd3dadapter9-mesa                                                                                         - state-tracker for Direct3D9                                                                                          
i   libd3dadapter9-mesa-dev                                                                                     - state-tracker for Direct3D9 -- development files                                                                     
i   libdrm-amdgpu1                                                                                              - Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime                                                
i   libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                                                                                         - Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime                                                
i   libdrm-common                                                                                               - Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- common files                                                           
i   libdrm-dev                                                                                                  - User-Space-Schnittstelle zu Kernel-DRM-Diensten -- Entwicklungsdateien                                               
i   libdrm-dev:i386                                                                                             - User-Space-Schnittstelle zu Kernel-DRM-Diensten -- Entwicklungsdateien                                               
i   libdrm-intel1                                                                                               - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu Intel-spezifischen Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                   
i   libdrm-intel1:i386                                                                                          - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu Intel-spezifischen Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                   
i   libdrm-nouveau2                                                                                             - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu nouveau-spezifischen Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                 
i   libdrm-nouveau2:i386                                                                                        - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu nouveau-spezifischen Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                 
i   libdrm-radeon1                                                                                              - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu Radeon-spezifischen Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                  
i   libdrm-radeon1:i386                                                                                         - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu Radeon-spezifischen Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                  
i   libdrm2                                                                                                     - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu den Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                                  
i   libdrm2:i386                                                                                                - Benutzerbereichsschnittstelle zu den Kernel-DRM-Diensten – Laufzeit                                                  
i A libegl-mesa0                                                                                                - free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library                                                            
i A libegl-mesa0:i386                                                                                           - free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library                                                            
i   libegl1-mesa                                                                                                - transitional dummy package                                                                                           
i   libegl1-mesa-dev                                                                                            - Freie Implementierung der EGL-API -- Entwicklungsdateien                                                             
i   libgbm-dev                                                                                                  - API für generische Pufferverwaltung -- Entwicklungsdateien                                                           
i   libgbm1                                                                                                     - API für generische Pufferverwaltung -- Laufzeit                                                                      
i   libgbm1:i386                                                                                                - API für generische Pufferverwaltung -- Laufzeit                                                                      
i   libgl1-mesa-dev                                                                                             - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files                                                       
i   libgl1-mesa-dev:i386                                                                                        - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files                                                       
i   libgl1-mesa-dri                                                                                             - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules                                                                 
i   libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                                                                                        - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules                                                                 
i   libgl1-mesa-glx                                                                                             - transitional dummy package                                                                                           
i   libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                                                                                        - transitional dummy package                                                                                           
i   libglapi-mesa                                                                                               - Freie Implementierung der GL-API - Laufzeitbibliothek                                                                
i   libglapi-mesa:i386                                                                                          - Freie Implementierung der GL-API - Laufzeitbibliothek                                                                
i   libgles2-mesa                                                                                               - transitional dummy package                                                                                           
i   libgles2-mesa-dev                                                                                           - free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- development files                                                    
i A libglx-mesa0                                                                                                - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library                                                          
i A libglx-mesa0:i386                                                                                           - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library                                                          
i A libllvm7                                                                                                    - Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library                                                         
i A libllvm7:i386                                                                                               - Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library                                                         
i   libosmesa6                                                                                                  - Mesa Off-screen rendering extension                                                                                  
i   libosmesa6:i386                                                                                             - Mesa Off-screen rendering extension                                                                                  
i   libosmesa6-dev                                                                                              - Mesa Off-screen rendering extension -- development files                                                             
i   libwayland-egl1-mesa                                                                                        - transitional dummy package                                                                                           
i   libxatracker2                                                                                               - X acceleration library -- runtime                                                                                    
i   llvm-7                                                                                                      - Modular compiler and toolchain technologies                                                                          
i A llvm-7-runtime                                                                                              - Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, IR interpreter                                                          
i   mesa-common-dev                                                                                             - Entwicklerdokumentation für Mesa                                                                                     
i   mesa-common-dev:i386                                                                                        - Entwicklerdokumentation für Mesa                                                                                     
i   mesa-opencl-icd                                                                                             - free implementation of the OpenCL API -- ICD runtime                                                                 
i   mesa-va-drivers                                                                                             - Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers                                                                               
i   mesa-va-drivers:i386                                                                                        - Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers                                                                               
i   mesa-vdpau-drivers                                                                                          - Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers                                                                                
i A mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386                                                                                     - Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers                                                                                
i   mesa-vulkan-drivers                                                                                         - Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
```

Comment: I have installed `vulkan-headers` package from mentioned PPA on clean *cosmic* VM, then ran `ppa-purge`. I can't reproduce your problem. To be completely sure please add output of `apt-cache policy ppa-purge` and `aptitude search '~O LP-PPA ?installed'` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert see updated question

Comment: I have had typo with aptitude - correct is  `aptitude search '~O LP-PPA ?installed'` .

Comment: For me it seems that you have some corruption of local ppa file-list files - you can check their contents manually (on */var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_dev_ubuntu_dists_cosmic_** path) or by greping for *install* word - `grep -w 'install' /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_graphics-drivers_dev_ubuntu_dists_cosmic_*` .

Comment: @N0rbert these files do not contain the string `install-`. I checked them manually and ran the proposed `grep` command.